# JSF Unit test getStyleClass requires FacesContext

Tags: unit-testing, jsf

I would like to add a unit test to test the style class gets set correctly. Unfortunately the getter `getStyleClass` requires a `FacesContext`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit). It's designed for exactly those purposes. Here's how it introduces itself:

> JSFUnit is a test framework for JSF applications. It is designed to allow complete integration testing and unit testing of JSF applications using a simplified API. JSFUnit tests run inside the container, which provides the developer full access to managed beans, the **FacesContext**, EL Expressions, and the internal JSF component tree. At the same time, you also have access to parsed HTML output of each client request.